# How to update billing_email when user_email is updated

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to achieve two way synchronization between `user_email` and `billing_email` (the key for woocommerce emails). So far, I have it working that when a customer edits/updates their billing email address their `user_email` gets updated with the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_customer_save_address','isa_customer_save_address', 10, 1);

function isa_customer_save_address() {

global $woocommerce;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

        wp_update_user( array ( 'ID' => $user_id, 'user_email' =>    $_POST['billing_email'] ) ) ;

}
```

Now how do I update a customer's `billing_email` when they edit/updates their `user_email`?

Comment: Hi hazem, what have you tried so far, or are you looking for an advice on how the trigger and action when the user's email changes?

Comment: @MarkKaplun i have edited the question

Answer (score 2):

This code should do it for you. It add an action to the updating of the WordPress profile, checks if the email has been updated, and if so, it updates the Woocommerce address as well.

```
add_action('profile_update', 'sync_woocommerce_email', 10, 2) ;

function sync_woocommerce_email( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ($current_user->user_email != $old_user_data->user_email) {
        wp_update_user( array ( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'billing_email' => $current_user->user_email ) ) ;
     }
}
```

**Edit:** I did something wrong here, I'm guessing its pretty basic I just haven't seen it yet.

Comment: it's not working , i don't know why

Comment: the problem is , when u say $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); u override the $old_user_data ,so what i mean is both $old_user_data and $current_user hold the same data

Comment: It's updating the `billing_email` if the `current_email` is **not equal** to the `old_user_data.` However, I'll do some testing to see if I did something wrong.